# Find Quick-Tabs id?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm new to drupal and I apologize if this is a silly question. I used the [quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module to create tabbed content. I wish to add it to a node template file. In order to add the quick tab, I need the ID of the quick tab instance. **How to find the ID of a quick tab instance** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the install file for the module each QuickTab is identified by a machine name, rather than an ID. It used to use an ID up until version 7.x-3.x, but the `quicktabs_update_7300()` function dropped the `qtid` field and replaced it with `machine_name`.

Normally when machine names are used in Drupal the admin UI will tell you what this is for each instance. I can't comment as to whether the QuickTabs UI does that though.

If it doesn't, just go in to the `quicktabs` table and grab the machine name from there...it's not pretty but if you don't plan on changing the machine name of that instance it shouldn't cause a problem.

After you've got the name you can use `quicktabs_load()` to get the instance:

```
$instance = quicktabs_load($machine_name);
```